# How to hide sub page of sub-domain tree from the main domain in typo3 8 LTS

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

I have website page tree down bellow:

```
   - Main domain 1 (main domain)
     - Home
     - about us
     - Contact
     - gallery
     - Sub domain 2 (sub-domain)
         - Home
         - about us
         - contact
         - gallery
```

Now, while main domain is active it shows the sub domain inner page too. I need only name of the domain (sub domain 2). while click in the link it will switch and redirect to the the sub-domain

Here is the HMENU typoscript:

```
lib.nav = HMENU
lib.nav.wrap = <nav id="primary-menu">|</nav>
lib.nav{
    special = directory
    special.value = 6
    # excludeUidList = 6

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        expAll = 1

        NO = 1
        NO {
            10 = TEXT
            10.data = field:title // field:nav_title
            10.wrap = |

            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            wrapItemAndSub.override.cObject = COA
            wrapItemAndSub.override.cObject {
                if {
                    value = 4
                    equals.field = doktype
                    isTrue = 1
                    isTrue.if {
                        value.data = TSFE:page|uid
                        equals.field = shortcut
                    }
                }
                10 = TEXT
                10.value = <li class="current">|</li>
            }

        }

        ACT = 1
        ACT.ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        ACT < .NO
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current">|</li>

        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="sub-menu" >|</li>
    }

    2 <.1
    2{
        wrap = <ul style="display: none;">|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            10 = TEXT
            10.data = field:title // field:nav_title
            10.wrap = |

            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            wrapItemAndSub.override.cObject = COA
            wrapItemAndSub.override.cObject {
                if {
                    value = 4
                    equals.field = doktype
                    isTrue = 1
                    isTrue.if {
                        value.data = TSFE:page|uid
                        equals.field = shortcut
                    }
                }
                10 = TEXT
                10.value = <li class="current">|</li>
            }

        }

        ACT = 1
        ACT.ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        ACT < .NO
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current">|</li>

        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="sub-menu" >|</li>        
    }
}
```

Here redirect link works fine with this, but while i'm browsing main domain site it will also shows the sub page of sub domain. Can anyone help me how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use `excludeUidList` Like below.

```
excludeUidList = 21,22  // Sub-page Uid with comma seprated like this
```

For Example.

```
lib.nav = HMENU
lib.nav.wrap = <nav id="primary-menu">|</nav>
lib.nav{
    excludeUidList = 21,22
    special = directory
    special.value = 6
    ....
    .....
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. i had tried before but what if new page create in the sub domain? Is there any way to manage this dynamic?

Comment: just exclude the uid of page "Sub domain 2 (sub-domain)". If you want a link in the menu of domain 1 use a (visible) shortcut/external url page. (in this way the tree of domain2 does not need to be below of domain1 at all)